# roots of Padé approximating polynomials to the exponential function

Tags: polynomials, roots, numerical-linear-algebra, pade-approximation

I need to obtain (numerically) the roots of the denominator in the Padé approximation to the exponential function $e^{-x}$, in Python. I can calculate its coefficients in closed form (see below). But the [`numpy.roots()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html#numpy.roots) function to find roots of a polynomial of known coefficients has a little footnote:

> The algorithm relies on computing the eigenvalues of the companion matrix [R279].

and the companion matrix becomes very ill-conditioned as the degree increases. (2-norm condition number of approx 2.23e+10 for a ratio of 9th-degree polynomials)

So it seems like I would be better off with a more direct approach to getting the roots; for matrix exponential $e^A$ the Padé coefficients for numerator $N_{pq}(A)$ of degree $p$ and denominator $D_{pq}(A)$ of degree $q$ for and are given in [p.9 of Moler and Van Loan's paper on matrix exponentials](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf#page=9); if I substitute $A=-x$ then I get this for the denominator:

$$D_{pq}(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^q\frac{(p+q-j)!q!}{(p+q)!j!(q-j)!}x^j$$

Is there a way to find the roots more directly? They are very nicely structured, I just don't know what that structure is; here is a complex-plane plot of the poles ("x") and zeros ("o") for $p=q=9$:

[image]

If I use `numpy.roots()` (which, again, relies on computing the eigenvalues of the companion matrix), then things seem to be ok for a while but then maybe break down...

$p=q=16$:

[image]

$p=q=27$:

[image]

$p=q=28$:

[image]

$p=q=32$:

[image]

and soon it looks like a marching band gone crazy (though symmetrically crazy in conjugate pairs).

Comment: Then we have Saff and Varga's paper [*On the Zeros and Poles of Padé Approximants to $e^z$*](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~esaff/texts/20.pdf) which looks tantalizingly relevant, but they don't compute the roots numerically, they just have proofs of general behavioral of where they are and aren't.

Comment: and Gonnet/Guettel/Trefethen's paper which also seems very relevant but I can't figure out how to apply it: http://www.guettel.com/download/gonnet_guettel_trefethen.pdf which I